# SignalR The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method

Tags: .net, signalr

I have C# .NET Framework SignalR Client application & ASP.NET Core 2.1 server. When i trying to start connection to SignalR Hub by WebSockets, i get exception.

```
System.AggregateException: Unable to connect to the server with any of the available transports.
 
--->
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.TransportFailedException: WebSockets failed: The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method. Имя параметра: name
 
    --->
    System.ArgumentException: The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method. Parameter name: name

        in System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ThrowOnRestrictedHeader(String headerName)
        in System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Set(String name, String value)
        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport..ctor(HttpConnectionOptions httpConnectionOptions, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, Func`1 accessTokenProvider)
        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.DefaultTransportFactory.CreateTransport(HttpTransportType availableServerTransports)
        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.<StartTransport>d__47.MoveNext() 

        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.<SelectAndStartTransport>d__44.MoveNext() 

        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.<SelectAndStartTransport>d__44.MoveNext() 

        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.<StartAsyncCore>d__41.MoveNext() 

        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.<StartAsync>d__40.MoveNext() 

        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext() 

        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext() 

        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.<StartAsyncCore>d__58.MoveNext() 

        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.<StartAsyncInner>d__50.MoveNext() 

        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.<StartAsync>d__49.MoveNext() 

        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
        in WPF.MainWindow.<<-ctor>b__4_4>d.MoveNext() in repository/MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 90 

 (#0) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.TransportFailedException: WebSockets failed: The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method Parameter name: name
 ---> System.ArgumentException: The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method Parameter name: name
    in System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ThrowOnRestrictedHeader(String headerName)
    in System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Set(String name, String value)
    in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport..ctor(HttpConnectionOptions httpConnectionOptions, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, Func`1 accessTokenProvider)
    in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.DefaultTransportFactory.CreateTransport(HttpTransportType availableServerTransports)
    in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.<StartTransport>d__47.MoveNext() 

    in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
    in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.<SelectAndStartTransport>d__44.MoveNext() 

  (#1) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.TransportFailedException: ServerSentEvents failed: The transport is disabled by the client.<--- 

 (#2) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.TransportFailedException: LongPolling failed: The transport is disabled by the client.
 <---
```

Code:

```
        HubConnection Connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl($"..", options => {
        options.UseDefaultCredentials = true; 
        options.Transports = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
        options.Headers["user-agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0";
    }).Build();


Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await Connection.StartAsync(); // exception thrown here
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // handle ex
                }
            });
```

I saw [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/198), [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24822) and [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/299), but i don't understand the solution that is attached there.

What User-Agent header i need to add for avoid this exception?

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Factory.StartNew`? Generally speaking, you should never need to use it.

Comment: I don't think it affects on the connection itself, but I'll change it to Task.Run...

Comment: (Correct, it isn't relevant, just general _best practice_), but you shouldn't need `Task.Run` either. Is there a reason the calling method can't be made `async`?

Comment: I've read through the GitHub links you posted - the root cause is a *design mistake* in the .NET Framework that's fixed in .NET Core (on the desktop), but is a `WONTFIX` in .NET Framework (bummer). The only workaround I can think of is to use reflection. That said, do you **need** to set a `User-Agent` header?

Comment: My main task is to get rid of this exception by any means

Comment: "My main task is to get rid of this exception by any means" - Then the simplest solution is to not set a custom `User-Agent` header at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a .NET Framework bug, switching to .NET Core helped me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections;

// 

static void HackWebSocketConfiguration( ClientWebSocketOptions wso )
{
    FieldInfo whcField = typeof(ClientWebSocketOptions).GetField( "requestHeaders", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic );
    WebHeaderCollection whc = (WebHeaderCollection)whcField.GetValue( wso );
    
    MethodInfo awov = typeof(ClientWebSocketOptions).GetMethod( "AddWithoutValidate", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic );
    awov.Invoke( whc, /*headerName:*/ "User-Agent", /*headerValue:*/ "Toaster/1.0" );
}

//

HubConnection Connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl( $"..", options =>
    {
        options.UseDefaultCredentials = true; 
        options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
        options.WebSocketConfiguration = ( ClientWebSocketOptions wso ) =>
        {
            HackWebSocketConfiguration( wso );
        };
    })
    .Build();
```

Comment: public abstract object MethodInfo.Invoke(object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture);

Comment: @Zerumi `MethodInfo.Invoke` has multiple overloads. My code uses the `MethodInfo.Invoke( Object, params Object[] )` overload.

Comment: you mean object obj and object[] args like awov.Invoke(whc, new object[] { "User-Agent", "Toaster/1.0" });?

Comment: @Zerumi You don't need to use `new Object[] {` for `params` arguments.

Comment: @Zerumi What is the exception and full stack-trace? My code shouldn't trigger the same `ThrowOnRestrictedHeader` exception because it takes a different code-path.

Comment: I debugged this moment and found out that the logic inside HackWebSocketConfiguration is not executing. Is it normal?